# python beautifulsoup : lxml html.parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, html-parser

I must use beautifulsoup, but i don't know which parser I have to take.
I hesitate between lxml and html.parser, or why not both.
How to know if a web page is lxml compliant ?
How to know if a web page is html parser compliant ?
Many thanks

Comment: "How to know if a web page is lxml compliant ?" http://lxml.de/validation.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no silver bullet. [Different HTML parsers behave differently](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) and you should pick the one that works for your particular page. Works in this case basically means, that you can get to your desired data.

`lxml` parser is generally faster, `html5lib` is the most lenient one - this kind of difference would be relevant if you have a broken or non-well-formed HTML to parse. `html.parser` is built-in and can help to avoid extra dependencies, if this is a problem. Here is a [related table](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) that highlights the differences.

Comment: So to be sure to get all the links, I must use several methods, several parsers?

Comment: @Anonymus nope, usually you just pick a parser and stick to it. But, I can imagine a page being non well-formed and parsing it with different parsers might get a bigger picture than with a single one. Though, I haven't been in that situation ever yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned it the hard way. It's been killing me. I just couldn't figure out why the tag I wanted included something that wasn't in that tag. Turned out the html parser wasn't working correctly with that site. After hours of headache, I suddenly tried switching to lxml parser, and lo and behold... The unwated stuff was gone as it should have been!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yeah yeah same thing, it turns out that html doesn't look good with bad closed tags, so lxml can handle this cases in a better way